# Jupyter Extension Installation Failed: Error says 'terminado' wasn't found, but I should already have it

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I've tried to install jupyter extensions following the instruction [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

The first step named 'Install the python package' in the instruction was succeeded.
But the second one named 'Install javascript and css files' was failed.
I executed `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` as instructed, but an error occured.

The error says: `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'terminado>=0.8.1' distribution was not found and is required by notebook`. (All traceback shown is as below.)
But I confirmed that I've already installed 'terminado' v0.8.2 package, which was installed via pip.

How can I handle this problem? Is the problem solely that jupyter command does not know where the 'terminado' is installed? Or is the problem more serious?

---

All the error message is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-contrib", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'terminado>=0.8.1' distribution was not found and is required by notebook
```

I'm using macOS Catalina (but same problem appeared on Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

The problem is, as it may be turned out with seeing the error message, that the `jupyter contrib` command uses python2, not python3 which is my preference.

### Problem

The usage of python2 by the command was caused by the shebang of `/usr/local/bin/jupyter-contrib` file.
The shebang was `#!/usr/bin/python`, which means that it specified `jupyter-contrib` used python interpreter which located on `/usr/bin/python` which is python2 on my machine (and many other Mac machine, maybe).
Hence you should specify python3 with the shebang rather than python2.

### Solution

1. First, get your python3 installation path like this:

   `$ which python3`

   Copy the returned path.
2. Open the `/usr/local/bin/jupyter-contrib` file. Note that this file is read-only but you have to rewrite it, so you should open it with `sudo`:

   `$ sudo vim /usr/local/bin/jupyter-contrib`
3. Rewrite the shebang on the 1st line. Shebang may now be like this:

   `#!/usr/bin/python`

   where it specifies python2 as its interpreter. You should rewrite the path to python3's path which you copied at step 1:

   `#!{{Paste your python3's path}}`
4. Save the file.

That's it.
Now `jupyter-contrib` uses python3.
So `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` command should succeeds.